# Property Declarations in Apple CoreData Templates

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

Reviewing the boilerplate code provided by apple for building the core data stack in swift, I find that there are two variables created for each item in the stack, e.g. managedObjectModel, and _managedObjectModel. My understanding is that the internal store variable for a property is created and managed internally by swift, so why do we have to create one manually? why can't we just create one property, and let swift handle the creation process, if one doesn't exist at time it is called. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Two properties are not being created - one is a *stored property* and one is a *computed property*.  The pattern is:

```
class Foo {
  var _bar : Bar
  var  bar : Bar { return _bar }
}
```

The `var _bar` is stored but `var bar` is computed.  The specific Apple pattern is used to lazily initialize the stored property like such:

```
class Foo {
  var _bar : Bar? = nil
  var  bar : Bar {
    if _bar == nil {
      /* compute some stuff */
      _bar = Bar (/* ... */)
    }
    return _bar!
  }
}
```

The above is used very much like a `@lazy property`.  You could make it one with:

```
class Foo {
  @lazy var bar : Bar = computeBar ()

  func computeBar () -> Bar {
    /* compute some stuff */
    return Bar (/* ... */)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. It clears a lot to me. So you can't use a single method/func/property that does both? Calculate a property, if it was not created, and store it for next use? How about the @lazy?? still doesn't store the property?? sorry for all the questions. I guess I can just copy and paste that boilerplate code, but I want to understand... Thanks again.

Comment: A `@lazy` does result in a stored property; the value of the property is computed the first time the lazy property is accessed. The Apple pattern used in their boilerplate code is, as you noted, amenable to @lazy.  See above edit.

Comment: You are welcome.  Would appreciate an 'answer checkmark'.  You might consider changing the title to be more descriptive - "Property Declarations in Apple CoreData Templates" maybe?

Comment: I am very new to stack overflow, as soon as I get enough reputations, I will add a checkmark. Thanks.